# Increase dimension of RNN LSTM cell in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to increase amount of recurrent weights in rnn or lstm cell.

If you look at the code below you will see, that lsrm cell inputs shape is (2,1), which means 2 timesteps and 1 feature.

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x
import tensorflow as tf

m = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
lstm = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(1, use_bias=False)
input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(2,1))

m.add(input)
m.add(lstm)

lstm.get_weights()
```

The output is

```
[array([[ 0.878217  ,  0.89324415,  0.404307  , -1.0542995 ]], dtype=float32),
 array([[-0.24181306, -0.341401  ,  0.65207034,  0.63227856]], dtype=float32)]
```

4 weights for each feature, and 4 weights for previous outputs

Now if I change Input shape like this

```
input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(2,1))

then the output of get_weights function will be like this:
[array([[-0.9725287 , -0.90078545,  0.97881985, -0.9623983 ],
        [-0.9644511 ,  0.90705967,  0.05965471,  0.32613564]], dtype=float32),
 array([[-0.24867296, -0.22346373, -0.6410606 ,  0.69084513]], dtype=float32)]
```

Now my question is: how do I increase amount of weights in the second array whick keeps the (4,1) shape?
The idea is that I want RNN or STRM take not only the previous output (t-1 moment) but more prevois values like (t-2, t-3, t-4) moments.

Is there way to do it in keras with tf backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't understand the change, I think you had a typo in your question, but:

### Length - Time steps:

The number of time steps will never change the number of weights. The layer is "recurrent", meaning it will "loop" the time steps. It's not supposed to have different weights for each step.

The whole purpose of the layer is to apply the same operations over and over and over for each time step.

### Input features:

Input features are the last dimension of the input. They define one dimension of the weights.

### Units = Output features:

Output features, also the last dimension of the output, are another dimension of the weights.

### Two types of kernels

The LSTM layers have two groups of kernels:

- What they call simply kernels - with `shape=(input_dim, self.units * 4)`
- What they call recurrent kernels - with  `shape=(self.units, self.units * 4)`

The first group acts on the input data, they have shape considering the input features and the output features.

The second group acts on inner states and have shapes considering only the output features (units).

From the source code:

```
        self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=(input_dim, self.units * 4),
                                      name='kernel',
                                      initializer=self.kernel_initializer,
                                      regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer,
                                      constraint=self.kernel_constraint)
        self.recurrent_kernel = self.add_weight(
            shape=(self.units, self.units * 4),
            name='recurrent_kernel',
            initializer=self.recurrent_initializer,
            regularizer=self.recurrent_regularizer,
            constraint=self.recurrent_constraint)
```

### The last array in the list:

The last array in the list of weights are the 4 recurrent kernels with shape `(1, 1)` grouped into one.

---

So:

- You can increase the `kernel`s with more input features. Transform `Input((anything, 1))` into `Input((anything, more))` for instance.
- You can increase the `kernel`s and the `recurrent_kernel`s (and biases, when considered) with bigger output features. Transform `LSTM(1, ...)` into `LSTM(more, ...)`
- Weights are independent of the lenght. It's even possible to have `Input((None, 1))`, meaning a variable length.

---

### Using more than just the last step

This should be automatic. LSTM layers are designed to have **memory**. The memory is an inner state that participates in all time steps. There are gates (the kernels) that decide how a new step will participate in this memory. Since all steps participate in the same memory, LSTM layer theoretically considers "all" time steps from the beginning.

So, you shouldn't really worry with this.

But if you do want this, there are maybe two ways. Don't know if they will bring any improvement, though.

One is to concatenate shifted inputs as features:

```
def pad_and_shift(x):
    steps = 3
    paddings = tf.constant([[0,0], [steps-1, 0], [0, 0]])
    x = tf.pad(x, paddings)

    to_concat = [ x[:,i:i - steps + 1] for i in range(steps-1) ]
    to_concat += x[:, steps-1:]

    return tf.concat(to_concat, axis=-1)


given_inputs = .... 
out = Lambda(pad_and_shift)(given_inputs)
out = LSTM(units, ...)(out)
```

The other involves editing the source code of the LSTM, which would be very complicated and probably not very worthy.

Comment: Yes. Weights amount is independent from amount of time-steps and depends on  features count.
but how do you set amount of features for reccurrent features?
How to make LSTM take not only previous output as current input, but also last by one?
P.S. In my code biases are set to false, set it it True and check how weights change.

Comment: Please refresh the page and see the updated answer.

Comment: The amount of features for recurrent features is based in `units` of the layer.

Comment: It has an initial transformation from `input_features` to `units` with a kernel that takes the two sizes into account. Then the recurrency occurs entirely with kernels based only on `units`. -- These are identified in the code as kernel and recurrent kernel.

Comment: Ok, @Demaunt, I finally understood your question. See the section "two types of kernels" in the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, seems like two type of kernels is what I am looking for.
As for amount of units I think each unit is unrolled independently, these must be hidden units, each of them taking one previous out, not last by one.

Comment: They're not related to steps, as explained in the last section. They just define the size of the inner states and the outputs. Every step takes the inner state, the last step output and the current input step, apply the kernels on them and produce an updated inner state and a new output step -- An initial look may lead us to think that they're like the units in a Dense layer, sort of parallel, but some of the kernel multiplications seem to mix them up a little.

Comment: Source code for one step: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L1970

Comment: Is it right to consider LSTM as layer with units equal to amount of neurons inside?
In this case increasing units to 2 will add additional neurons in hidden layer. That means that hidden_neuron_1 at t-time step will take self previous output at t-1 and previous output from hidden_neuron_2 as inputs.
They dont last by one outputs as inputs.

Comment: You can think of them as neurons, yes, but again, they're not related to steps. They all act in parallel. Neuron 1 and neuron 2 will "together" take the last step and the current input step and the inner state, they will operate "together" in these and produce "together" a new output step and an unpdated inner state. --- The same two neurons, again in a new iteration, will "together" take the new output, a new step from the input, the updated inner state, and operate again.

Comment: Thank you for making it clear that time_steps do not affect dimension of weights, it realy opened my eyes.

But as you have said: "Neuron 1 and neuron 2 will "together" take the last step and the current input step...".

Is it possible to make 2 units in LSTM-layer: Neuron 1 and neuron 2 take last !!! AND last but one (penult) !!! each other outputs combined with current value of time-series as input for both?
I realy am bothered by LAST outputs, I want to find way using last but one and even more old outputs fur current input

Comment: Not without changing the source code. You can try to add a convolution before and/or after, which will process near steps with the size of the kernel.

Comment: You can try Conv + LSTM + Conv + LSTM + Conv, for instance. This should create sort of a step mix up.